# Redirect to url from Javascript executed on server side

Tags: javascript, alfresco

I've an Alfresco workflow implemented in Javascript (server side). In a specific step of my workflow (a javascript function) I call a Java method from Javascript that moves the current space for another space which the current user don't have access.

Everything works fine but a correct "access denied error" is exhibited to the user at the end of the execution of Javascript function.

My question is:

Is there a way to redirect the user for another URL after the execution of a Javascript function executed in the server side?

Below you can see a piece of code of the Javascript function:

```
        var f = function() { 
            originalLocation = space.properties["sgiStdWF:spaceOriginalLocation"];
            var originalSpace = getSGIRootSpace(space).childByNamePath("DocsControlados" + originalLocation);
            space.move(originalSpace);  
        }

        sudoUtils.sudo(f,"System");
```

Note that the current user (responsible to execute this javascript function) doesn't have access to originalSpace.

I use the Java method (sudoUtils) because I need privilege to move the space to another space which the current user doesn't have access (is a kind of runAs). (http://fabiostrozzi.eu/2009/11/23/sudo-like-tool-for-alfresco-webscripts/)

At the end of the day everything is working fine. The main problem is that the user can be confused with the "access denied error".

I hope you understand my question. :-)

Comment: Does current user have permission on destination space? where exactly on UI you are getting this access denied exception?

Comment: Initially the user has permission, but after move the space to other place the user cant't access the space anymore. This is the expected behavior (i.e. I don't want the user accessing the space after the action of move). Since the user can't access the space, he receives an "access denied error" after the end of the javascript execution.